# what is the difference between "take out an attempt" and "make an attempt"?

Tags: difference

Here is the piece of text where I happened upon the phrase *take out an attempt*:

> To that end, there must be a reduction in both volume and intensity starting about 10 days out from the competition. In the week to ten days prior to the meet, the lifter should not be grinding out high volume sets of 5, nor should he be **taking out maximum attempts**.

Could the author just say *...making maximum attempts* or *taking maximum attempts*? Does the phrase *take out an attmept* have a particular shade in meaning?

Comment: The phrase makes no sense to me.

Comment: In weight-lifting, a **one-rep maximum** is a particular type of lift (meaning the maximum weight you can lift exactly once with correct form), so a **maximum attempt** is an attempt to lift your one-rep maximum weight.  However, **taking out** is not usual here - I would expect **making maximum attempts**.